# Usage of combinatorics in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Could use some help or insights, cause I'm going nuts..

- **Situation**: I have a table of players ID's, with values 1,2,3.. to 7.
- **Objective**: Want to create a roster of 4 players, from available players (in our case there are 7 of them). Its a classical combinatoric task, we need to calculate C(k,n). In our case C(4,7)=840/24=35. So, there are possible 35 ways to build a roster. I want to create a table of rosters with player ID's. Here's the current script, that builds the current roster table:

`with comb_tbl as(
      select
        tmp_out.row_num,
        regexp_substr(tmp_out.comb_sets,'[^,]+',1,1) plr_id_1,
        regexp_substr(tmp_out.comb_sets,'[^,]+',1,2) plr_id_2,
        regexp_substr(tmp_out.comb_sets,'[^,]+',1,3) plr_id_3,
        regexp_substr(tmp_out.comb_sets,'[^,]+',1,4) plr_id_4
      from(
        select
          rownum row_num,
          substr(tmp.combinations,2) comb_sets
        from(
          select
            sys_connect_by_path(plr.plr_id, ',') combinations
          from(
            select 1 plr_id from dual union
            select 2 plr_id from dual union
            select 3 plr_id from dual union
            select 4 plr_id from dual union
            select 5 plr_id from dual union
            select 6 plr_id from dual union
            select 7 plr_id from dual) plr
          connect by nocycle prior plr.plr_id != plr.plr_id) tmp
        where
          length(substr(tmp.combinations,2)) = 7) tmp_out)
    select
      tmp1.*
    from
      comb_tbl tmp1`

- **Problem**:Its creates 840 possibilities, but I need to remove the "identical" ones, for example roster (1,2,3,4) is "identical" to roster (2,1,3,4). Any insights/comments/critics are welcome. Maybe the approach itself is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a 1-1 correspondence between possible rosters and ORDERED subsets of four elements of the seven-element set.

In your `CONNECT BY` clause, you only check that the player id's be different, rather than that they be in increasing order. Change `!=` to `<` in `CONNECT BY` and it will work. (Also, you won't need `NOCYCLE` anymore.)

Comment: You can also simplify things by adding `and level <= 4` into the initial connect by statement, plus removing the redundant `nocycle`. Also, if you output the level as a column, you can then filter on that column, rather than your `length(substr(tmp.combinations,2)) = 7`, so the filter becomes something like `lvl = 4` which - IMO - is much clearer and easier to understand.

Comment: @Boneist - I assume you meant that as a comment addressed to the OP, not to me?

Comment: @mathguy d'oh, I did, yes!

Answer (score 2):

This could be a join way:

```
with plr(plr_id) as 
    ( select level from dual connect by level <= 7)
select p1.plr_id, p2.plr_id, p3.plr_id, p4.plr_id
from plr p1
      inner join plr p2
        on(p1.plr_id < p2.plr_id)  
      inner join plr p3
        on(p2.plr_id < p3.plr_id)
      inner join plr p4
        on(p3.plr_id < p4.plr_id)
```

For example, with `n=5` you would have:

```
    PLR_ID     PLR_ID     PLR_ID     PLR_ID
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1          2          3          4
         1          2          3          5
         1          2          4          5
         1          3          4          5
         2          3          4          5
```

Comment: Thank you. This variation works too. Sad, can't accept several answers. +1

Comment: This is what `CONNECT BY` does. A hierarchical query is nothing but iterated self-joins.

Answer (score 1):

**This is not an answer; it's merely a continuation of my earlier comment:**

By making those additional changes, your query could end up something like:

```
SELECT regexp_substr(tmp_out.comb_sets,'[^,]+',1,1) plr_id_1,
       regexp_substr(tmp_out.comb_sets,'[^,]+',1,2) plr_id_2,
       regexp_substr(tmp_out.comb_sets,'[^,]+',1,3) plr_id_3,
       regexp_substr(tmp_out.comb_sets,'[^,]+',1,4) plr_id_4
FROM   (SELECT sys_connect_by_path(plr.plr_id, ',') comb_sets,
               LEVEL lvl
        FROM   (select 1 plr_id from dual union all
                select 2 plr_id from dual union all
                select 3 plr_id from dual union all
                select 4 plr_id from dual union all
                select 5 plr_id from dual union all
                select 6 plr_id from dual union all
                select 7 plr_id from dual) plr
        CONNECT BY PRIOR plr.plr_id < plr.plr_id
                   AND LEVEL <= 4) tmp_out
WHERE lvl = 4;
```

which is, IMO, easier to read and understand than your original query.